# Amazon SQS Content based deduplication with delivery delay?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Content based de-duplication in FIFO queues works for 5 min.

What if i put on a delivery delay (default : 0) to 5 min also?

Will the de-duplication still work ?

ie if 3 duplicate messages where delivered within the 5 min interval, on the 6th minute i see only 1 message ?

Comment: Feel free to try it for yourself and let us know what you find!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could not find any information or documentation related to this.
Tried it on a SQS queue, and the de-duplication does work.

If delivery delay is set to 5 min (same as def deduplication time), duplicated messages are ignored even though the message has not entered the queue.

Actually it seems its just not visible to us (same as visibility timeout), so the message enters and the deduplication id is generated by sqs to track the message.